# Audio API para calcular a duração de várias músicas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html5-audio

Estou trabalhando em um *player* de áudio e preciso saber como calcular a duração de várias MP3 que são selecionadas na máquina do usuário por um `input` do tipo `file`?

**EDIT:**

Segue meu código atual e que não retorna o valor correto...

```
var audioElement2 = document.createElement('audio');
var fill;
var tamanho = 0;
$("#file666").change(function() {
    fill = this.files.length;


    for (var i = 0; i < fill; i++) {
    file3[i] = this.files[i];

    fileB = URL.createObjectURL(file3[i]);
    audioElement2.setAttribute('src', fileB);

    $(audioElement2).on("loadedmetadata", function () {
    tamanho = tamanho + parseInt(audioElement2.duration);
    });

    }


    $("#musicas").html("Músicas Carregadas: " + fill + " (Tempo Total: " + tamanho + ")");
});
```

Estou tentando usar um loop for com uma variavel somando todas as mp3 mas não dá certo, ele retorna "0" como resultado...

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f6dxt5s/)**

Comment: Aparentemente só é possível ler a duração ***depois*** que o áudio foi injetado na `src` da tag `<audio>`. Testei algumas bibliotecas para ler o ID3 que permitem ler as propriedades de cada `this.files[i]`, mas muitas vezes a informação `Length` não consta do arquivo MP3.

Comment: Tinha pensado em responder, mas como o Tony já matou a charada, deixo os links da minha pesquisa: [**1**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255063/), [**2**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912231/), [**3**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581540/), [**4**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443105/), [**5**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606393/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **loademetadata** é um evento, por isto você quase conseguiu:
ele vai sendo chamado e você precisa incrementar uma variável para armazenar o Tempo Total e atualizar a *interface com usuário* a cada vez que o evento ocorrer.

Talvez a melhor forma seja ligar esta variável ao **HTML**, usando **AngularJS**.

JSfiddle com código em http://jsfiddle.net/7f6dxt5s/18/

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInputSelector" size="60" name="fileInputSelector" multiple>
<div id="musicas">Músicas Carregadas: 0 (Tempo Total: 0 segundos)</div>
```

Código

```
var tempoTotal = 0;

$("#fileInputSelector").change(function () {
    var quantidadeDeArquivos = this.files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < quantidadeDeArquivos; i++) {
        var esteArquivo = this.files[i];
        fileB = URL.createObjectURL(esteArquivo);

        var audioElement2 = new Audio(fileB);
        audioElement2.setAttribute('src', fileB);
        audioElement2.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
            tempoTotal = tempoTotal + parseInt(this.duration);
            $("#musicas").html("Músicas Carregadas: " + quantidadeDeArquivos + " (Tempo Total: " + tempoTotal + " segundos)");
            //alert("loadedmetadata" + tempoTotal);
        }
    }
    tempoTotal = 0;
});
```

Comment: estranho, ele soma só a duração da última música...

Comment: Renomeei as variáveis, para melhor leitura. Atualizei a resposta. Agora ficou funcionando corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Em html5 existe a propriedade `duration`

No seu caso ficaria algo parecido com:

```
duracao = audioElement.duration
```

Lembrando que o retorno vai ser em segundos!

Para converter de segundos para minutos/horas eu uso o módulo [moment](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/reference/business-logic/reference.html#moment-module).

segue código:

```
var seconds = audioElement.duration;
var duration = moment.duration(seconds, "seconds");

var time = "";
var hours = duration.hours();
if (hours > 0) { time = hours + ":" ; }

time = time + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
```

Comment: na verdade é para calcular a duração de várias mp3 ao mesmo tempo!!! estou tentando usar um loop for com uma variavel somando todas as mp3 mas não dá certo...

Comment: "não dá certo" é muito vago, um loop funcionaria perfeitamente, na realidade não tem muitas alternativas, você vai precisar caminhar dentro de um loop pegando o duration de cada mp3, no fim das contas você vai ter uma soma total de todos os arquivos selecionados em segundos, ai é só converter para horas/minutos

Comment: eder, o problema é que o `duration` só está disponível *depois* que um elemento de áudio foi setado com um `src`, o loop `new Audio + setAttribute` na resposta do Tony.

Comment: Boa @brasofilo na verdade eu não tinha notado que estava faltando o `new Audio` no código do @aps ...

Answer (score 1):

Para analizar a duração do arquivo MP3, o modo mais fácil (e talvez até eficiente), é iterar em todos os arquivos selecionados, ler seus conteúdos e interpretar o cabeçalho de arquivo.

**Leitura dos Dados**

Seja `file` do tipo `File`, você pode ler dados do seguinte modo:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        // evt.target.result; <-- contém os bytes lidos.
  }
};

var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1); // start = 0, stop deve ser grande o suficiente.
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

**Interpretação do Header**

Agora ou você constrói um parser ou utiliza um que ja existe. Recomendo o [mp3-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mp3-parser). Após ter feito a referência ao JS baixado, utilize:

```
var tags = mp3Parser.readTags(new DataView(/* bytes do mp3 */));
```

Agora, basta examinar a variável `tags` para obter todas as informações desejadas.

**Juntando...**

O código para interpretar um único arquivo então ficará semelhante a:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
        var tags = mp3Parser.readTags(new DataView(evt.target.result));
        // basta analisar a variável tags.
  }
};

var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

A análise da variável `tags` e a integração do código proposto com o código da questão ficam como exercício ;D