# Dados recebidos do audio

Tags: html5, html5-audio

Como saber o quanto de dados (KBs ou MBs) da tag audio foi recebida?
Por exemplo, o usuário entra no site, e clica em play, o audio começa a tocar. Vamos supor que a internet dele seja muito ruim e a musica fica parando toda hora.
Como saber não necessariamente a porcentagem, mas sim o valor da quantidade dos dados recebidos apenas pela tag `<audio>`, alem de saber o tamanho completo do arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pra fazer isso você vai precisar conhecer alguns atributos sobre o áudio a ser transmitido,  como se o áudio é mp3 (existe compressão) ou sera PCM (sem compressão), arquivos deste tipo são os conhecidos wav, além disso você vai precisar conhecer se a transmissão será em mono ou stereo além do frame rate e em qual taxa de bits a transmissão do áudio está sendo feita, com estas informações você poderá calcular com precisão o tamanho do seu áudio em qualquer segundo/mili-segundo, para conhecer o tamanho total do arquivo, olhe a seguinte resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32116/audio-api-para-calcular-a-dura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-v%C3%A1rias-m%C3%BAsicas/)

Ou seja ao calcular quantos segundos/minutos  tem o seu arquivo é possível calcular qual o tamanho total dele também.

Para mp3 em mono a fórmula geral é a seguinte:

```
Taxa de bits do seu audio / 8
```

Isso vai ser igual a quantos bytes por segundo foi recebido ou seja se o arquivo tocou um segundo será o valor deste cálculo, agora some isso para ir acumulando a cada segundo tocado.

Se você conseguiu o tamanho total do seu arquivo em segundos então para conhecer o tamanho total em bytes siga a fórmula geral novamente.

```
Taxa de bits do seu audio / 8 × X segundos do seu áudio
```

Lembrando que se for transmissão stereo  então dois canais são utilizados e nestes casos faça o resultado vezes 2.